# Is there a Welch-like correction for the standard deviation of Mann-Whitney U or Wilcoxon W?

Tags: variance, nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

The Mann-Whitney U test or the Wilcoxon Rank Sum test is sensitive to unequal variances. Is there an equation that adjusts the standard deviation of this statistic, much like in the Welch-corrected t-test for independent samples?

Comment: Who says it "is sensitive to unequal variances"?

Comment: By sensitive, I mean the false positive rate increases with increases differences in variances between to two populations. I'm not sure who says this, but it's true.

Comment: How do you know it's true?